# My handler doesn't instantly get notification when a message sent to it

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I use two search thread and a filter thread to search for the file I want.
After the FileFilter found the matched file, the passed-in parameter 'handler' will obtainMessage to notify m_handler in MainActivity to update the UI.

It was fine before they work without thread pool (Excecutor). After I have my threads activated by Executor in Controller.java, my file view UI doesn't instantly update when message sent From FileFilter.

After viewing the log, the hanlder message notifications don't show until the two search threads end, and that cause my UI to get stuck till threads end. It seems that the notifications get stuck because of the try-catch block in Controller.java cuz the executor was waiting for the result of the two seach threads. After leaving the startSearching() function in Controller.java, the notifications to the target m_handler in MainActivity then can be informed to update. That is, UI delayed till the end.

My way I deliver the variable of my handler: MainActivity -> Controller -> FileFilter

How can I solve this problem?

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Handler m_handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Log.d("myLog", "UI handler got informed to update.");
            switch (msg.what){
                case 1:
                    File receivedFile = (File) msg.obj;
                    addFilesToAdapter(receivedFile);
            }
        }
    };

    private Controller m_controller = new Controller();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        m_btn_search.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    List<String> strListInputText = detectEditTextInputStatus();
                    m_controller.startSearching(m_handler, strListInputText);
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Controller Class

```
public class Controller {

    public void startSearching(Handler handler, List<String> strListInputText) {
        CallBack forSearchAndFilter = new SharedFiles();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        //my 1st search thread
        FileSearcher searchCallable = new FileSearcher(forSearchAndFilter);
        Future<Boolean> result = executor.submit(searchCallable);

        //my 2ed search thread
        FileSearcher SecSearchCallable = new FileSearcher(forSearchAndFilter);
        Future<Boolean> result2 = executor.submit(SecSearchCallable);

        executor.shutdown();

        //my filter thread
        if (strListInputText != null) { //has input
            Runnable filterRunnable  = new FileFilter(forSearchAndFilter, handler, strListInputText);
            Thread filterThread = new Thread(filterRunnable);
            filterThread.start();
        }

        //this try catch block cause my UI to get stuck
        try {
            Log.d("myLog", "result: " + result.get());
            Log.d("myLog", "result2: " + result2.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        forSearchAndFilter.setFinishedPutFile(true); //inform filter thread that the two search threads have finished
        Log.d("myLog", "All thread tasks done");

    }
}
```

FileFilter Class

```
public class FileFilter implements Runnable {
    private Handler m_handler;

    public FileFilter(CallBack callBackToTakeFile, Handler handler, List<String> strListinputText) {
        this.m_callBackToTakeFile = callBackToTakeFile;
        this.m_handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (matchedFile != null) {
            m_handler.obtainMessage(1, matchedFile).sendToTarget(); //Send matched file to UI
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @pskink to check if my callable (two search threads) return true. Atfer the two search threads end, it will inform filter thread. So startSearching() function won't leave untill the two search thread finish. I think the handler messages might be stuck in that stack.

Comment: @pskink yah I ignore the return value of Future#get method, but it's the way  to wait for the two search threads to finish so that they can inform the filter thread that the search work has finished. As for filterThread, it's not related to executor. The executor is for the two search threads. The try-catch block doesn't end till the two search threads end. This is the way I use to inform the filterThread, but it thus cause the UI to stuck.

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? i see `addFilesToAdapter`, so do you want to filter-out some `ListView` adapter? are you aware of `Filterable` interface? its docs say: *"Defines a filterable behavior. A filterable class can have its data constrained by a filter. Filterable classes are usually Adapter implementations."*, what adapter are you using?

Comment: I want the messages sent from m_handler.obtainMessage(1, matchedFile).sendToTarget(); in FileFilter to be instantly handled by the handler in MainActivity. I don't want them to get stuck by the try-catch. The adapter I use is a ListView or a GridView. I don’t use Filterable.

Comment: then simply dont call `result.get()`, thats all

Comment: But my filter thread will instantly end.

Comment: instantly end? what do you mean?

Comment: `forSearchAndFilter.setFinishedPutFile(true);` will be instantly executed to  inform filter thread to finish before the two search threads finish searching.

Comment: The filter thread's life is determined by the life of the two search threads. `setFinishedPutFile()` is for that to inform filter thread. The function doesn't be executed till the two search threads end. And I don't want my UI to get stuck because of that.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/7YrgXdkE

Comment: Nice example! It works. :)